# Admin Trogdor Needed to Burninate Many Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I just finished submitting 15 tag descriptions that are now sitting in the review queue. My hope and earnest expectation is that these will assist users in properly assigning tags to new questions.

While editing, I noticed the following problems:

- [twisty-puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twisty-puzzles), [3x3x7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3x3x7), [5x5x5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5x5x5) are all duplicates of [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)
- [brainfuck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck) is an esoteric programming language; it doesn't warrant its own tag on this site
- [paper-solving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-solving) is a duplicate of [pencil-and-paper-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-and-paper-games)
- [naming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) is a duplicate of [puzzle-identification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification)
- [layout](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) has only one associated question, which is related to crossword layouts. [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) would work well to replace this.
- [intuitive-solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitive-solution) also has only one associated question, which asks how to solve an unusual puzzle by Oskar van Deventer. My suggestion would be a more general [how-to-solve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to-solve) tag to apply to questions asking about how to solve a particular puzzle. There is an existing tag for this, [explanation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explanation), and I submitted a description for it, but [how-to-solve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to-solve) seems much more intuitive.
- [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) is a duplicate of [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message), and appears in only one question
- [guessing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guessing) and [smiley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smiley) are superfluous and should be removed
- [mpire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mpire) is a duplicate of [map-coloring](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-coloring)

My suggestion, for what it's worth, is that the aforementioned duplicates and superfluous tags be synonymized or burninated by any user with sufficient privileges to do so. I would do so myself, but it doesn't appear as though I can do so even subject to oversight.

And my apologies if some or all of these issues appear in other meta threads, but at least now there's a record of them all in one place.

Comment: In general, I definitely agree (and we're in need of some _serious_ tag cleanup), but I'd argue that [tag:twisty-puzzles] is actually broader than [tag:rubiks-cube], and in that case, I'd suggest synonymizing in the other direction.

Comment: @Emrakul can we really not come up with a more descriptive tag name than twisty-puzzles? Possibly [combination-puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_puzzle)

Comment: @Joe Hmm... when I originally created that tag, I did so because "twisty puzzles" is the generally accepted name for them. See: [the Twisty Puzzles Forum](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/forum)

Comment: @Joe I think I suggested mechanical-puzzles a while back.

Comment: @JoeZ This is true; "mechanical puzzles" does sound a lot more... professional, for lack of a better word, than "twisty puzzles."

Comment: I officially propose mechanical-puzzles as the canonical tag, then.

Comment: @JoeZ Want to start a new meta question on it?

Comment: Actually, there's already an [old meta question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/should-mechanical-puzzles-and-twisty-puzzles-be-synonymised) on the matter, and you already answered it. :P

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to remove a tag is to edit it out of every question that has it. The tag will disappear from the list after a little while (there's an automatic cleanup job that runs daily).

If a tag is present on a lot of questions, then Stack Exchange staff can [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/101417#101417) it, i.e. make it so that the tag never existed. This is only done when editing all the questions would require a lot of work and would overwhelm the front page by bumping every question that had it. For a tag that's only present on a handful of questions, remove it normally.

Creating tag synonyms can be done by moderators (and in practice only by moderators — there's a community voting process but it's very difficult to reach the vote threshold). Moderators can also effectively rename a tag (by creating a synonym then removing the original).

In both cases, it's best to discuss on meta if the optimal action is not obvious.

I've done the ones I consider clear-cut:

- [3x3x7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3x3x7) and [5x5x5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5x5x5) are overly specific, their one question each should probably be retagged to [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube). Done.
- Edited [brainfuck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck) out of [100 sequential parking spaces](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/100-cars-and-a-parking) which is unrelated. Left it on [Is there a general strategy for decoding Brainfuck mutations?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/is-there-a-general-strategy-for-decoding-brainfuck-mutations) since it is about Brainfuck. Added a tag wiki.
- [layout](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) is pretty meaningless. Retagged [Are there "rules" (or consistent conventions) that limit when the NY Times Crossword can deviate from rotational symmetry?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-rules-or-consistent-conventions-that-limit-when-the-ny-times-cross) to [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) [crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords).
- [intuitive-solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitive-solution) is a meta tag: it doesn't say what the question is about, and it's a subjective judgement. Out with it.
- [guessing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guessing)? [smiley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smiley)? Out, damn pointless tag, out!

Regarding the others:

- I don't think [twisty-puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twisty-puzzles) is a duplicate of [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube), it's a generalization.
- [paper-solving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-solving) isn't the same thing as [pencil-and-paper-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-and-paper-games): one is about effectively solving on paper, the other is about something that is meant to be solved on paper, or to be played on paper and solved mentally.
- [naming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) (what is this puzzle called?) isn't exactly the same as [puzzle-identification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification) (where is this puzzle from?), but close enough.
- [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message) should be a synonym of [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, Gilles. I've submitted a tag wiki for [tag:paper-solving] to clarify its purpose. I also noticed another duplicate: [tag:arithmetic] is only used by one puzzle and is a synonym for [tag:calculation-puzzle].